# Why is Chrome loading my HTML in a "pre" tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, arduino

I have a very basic web page that I'm loading with an Arduino Server.  When I view the page on Safari, everything works fine and looks good when I use the inspector.  But when I load it on Chrome (version 39.0.2), it wraps all of my HTML in a "pre" tag which prevents my webpage from loading (I've attached screenshots showing the Inspector output).  It also moves all of my code out of the "head" tag and into the "body" tag.  First, here is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>



    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

         <!-- LOAD THE JSON DATA -->
              <script type="text/javascript" src="data.txt"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
              <script src="home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




        <title>CANARI JR. | Home</title>

    </head>


<body onload="preparePage()">

<div id="container">


    <div id="headerDiv">

        <div id="logoDiv"><a href="/">
         <img src="cLogo.png"> 
        </div></a>





     </div>



<div id="contentDiv">


</div>



</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I inspect my page,  I see this:

And it wraps around all my HTML and actually closes the tag outside of my body and html tag!

Anyone see what is going wrong here in Chrome?

Edit 1 - I am using an Arduino Ethernet Shield to host and load this page from an SD card.  (It works perfectly on Safari, so I'm thinking there's something in my code and not an issue with Arduino).

Edit 2 - I've attached screenshot of the Google Chrome Inspector (sorry - copy and pasting replaced a lot of the characters, so I went screenshot route
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d09k8.png

Edit 3 - Added "Network" Tab from Chrome Inspector https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL7L1.png

Comment: Is this code what safari tells you it is or your raw output? How does it look when you view the source in chrome. Also have a look at the `Network` tab in chrome dev tools and see what content type your page is delivered with.

Comment: Can you share the chrome inspect out also. I tried your same page without js it renders perfectly.

Comment: The code I have is my raw HTML code in Sublime Text Editor.  In Safari Inspector, it looks the same and loads perfect.  I added the chrome inspect output.

Comment: Chrome does this when your code is delivered as text/plain, without any content type or is very invalid HTML. Your screenshots do not show the `Network` tab of the inspector though.

Comment: There you have it, its transferred as `text/plain`.

Comment: Added Network Tab.  I'm trying to validate via validator.w3.org and it says "No Character Encoding Found! Falling back to UTF-8.

None of the standards sources gave any information on the character encoding labeling for this document. Without encoding information it is impossible to reliably validate the document. As a fallback solution, the "UTF-8" encoding was used to read the content and attempt to perform the validation, but this is likely to fail for all non-trivial documents."  But in my HTML I have     <meta charset="utf-8" />  Could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: Not really, as stated in my comments, its because of the content type your server delivers it with.

Comment: Have a look at [this code snippet](http://startingelectronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/basic-web-server/) he sets the content type.

Comment: @LJ_1102 YES!  That's it!  I added                           client.println("Content-Type: text/html"); when my Arduino Server opens the page and it's fixed!  That's the answer so if you'd like to post it, I'll accept it.  Thanks a lot, it was bugging me for 2 hours.  Strange how it worked with Safari.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your sceenshots the page is delivered with the `Content-type: text/plain` header.
This leads chrome to display it in a `pre` tag as it assumes you want to view the HTML as text.
Your webserver needs to write a proper `Content`-type header.

An example of how to write headers using the arduino ethernet shield [can be found here](http://startingelectronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/basic-web-server/).

Contrary to the code linked above, you should determine the content-type dynamically, using something like the file extension. So that images are transferred with the correct content-type(for example `image/jpg`) aswell.

Answer (score -1):

Add Dependency to your POM

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. To me, it looks pretty weird that some POM should be edited, as the OP has not mentioned anything like that