# CSP Violation when using produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE with Spring

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I'm using Java and Spring and I wrote a simple GET Request-Handler Method that simply returns a String. I also want this to show as plaintext so I chose the ContentType text/plaintext (produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)

```
@GetMapping(path = BASE_URI, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String view() {
      return "bla bla"
}
```

When opening this page with Google Chrome. I'm constantly getting a CSPViolationReport.
The CSP sees style-src-attr as violated. Since I haven't defined anything for style-src-attr the config falls back to style-src-attr = 'self'
Chrome doesn's simply show the text but wraps it with html. This html includes some inline-styling.

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">bla bla</pre>
```

It seems to me that Chrome is introducing the violation itself since the styling doesn't come from 'self'

Have you already experienced a similar issue? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914693/why-is-chrome-loading-my-html-in-a-pre-tag/27915048)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Vusal. But from what I understand the content here is delivered as text/plain _deliberately_. So how can Chrome be prevented from causing the CSP violation when you want do deliver plain text?

Comment: @Felizett exactly.